# How to determine if a given int64_t can be stored losslessly in a double?

Tags: c++, precision

I'd like to determine if a given 64-bit integer can be stored losslessly in a double. Right now I have this code:

```
static_cast<int64_t>(static_cast<double>(value)) == value
```

However, I believe this is not always accurate due to [excess precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503436/how-to-deal-with-excess-precision-in-floating-point-computations) on some platforms.

Note that I'm not asking for the [largest integer such that all smaller integers can be stored losslessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double), which is 2^53. I need to know if a given integer N is losslessly storeable even if N+1 and N-1 are not.

Is there something in the standard library, maybe similar to `std::numeric_limits`, that will tell me this?

Comment: What's actually wrong checking against `std::numeric_limits`?

Comment: If the distance between the most significant non-zero bit and the least significant non-zero bit of the positive value is less or equal to `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits` I'd think the `int64_t` can be stored losslessly in a `double` (I think it is less or equal but there is a chance that I got an off by one error here).

Comment: doesn't Christoph's answer demonstrate via the standard wording that a cast will "remove all extra range and precision"

Comment: Checking `std::numeric_limits` will give me the 2^53 boundary, but won't tell me if a given integer >2^53, like 2^54, will fit. It also assumes IEEE representation if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as low bits are 0, you can have more high order bits set (because you can increase the double's exponent). I reduced the requirement to unsigned to make the bit shifting not have to worry about sign bits but I believe it should be adaptable.

```
bool fits_in_double_losslessly (uint64_t v)
{
    const uint64_t largest_int = 1ULL << 53;

    while ((v > largest_int) && !(v & 1))
    {
        v >>= 1;
    }

    return v <= largest_int;
}
```

Comment: Does this assume IEEE representation?

Comment: This indeed looks like IEEE 754.  If you have a Linux system, then you can examine /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ieee754.h to see how floating point values are internally represented.  Within this file you can see that mantissa0 has 20 bits and mantissa1 has 32 bits (totally 52 bits).  This implies that a 64-bit integer can populate any consecutive 52 bits loselessly.
For completeness, you can loselessly store consecutive 23 bits into a float and (if supported) all 64 bits into a long double.

Comment: You'd need to remove the sign-bit first... And I'm not aware of any HW available "with ease" that isn't IEEE-compatible (at least as far as the layout of the bits - there are some implementations that "cheat" on the specifics of rounding, required precision in some calculations, and so on)

Comment: The original code snippet would go into an infinite loop if the value being tested was 0; I edited it to reflect what I believe works.

Answer (score 2):

Subtract the highest bit set from the lowest bit set, add one to avoid fencepost error, compare to the number of bits in the mantissa.  Remember that the leading 1 of the mantissa is implicit in IEEE.  If the mantissa can hold the entire range of bits in use, it can store that number exactly.

Alternatively, see if `static_cast<double>(m) != static_cast<double>(m+1) && static_cast<double>(m) != static_cast<double>(m-1)`.  This works for an *unsigned* value, but for a *signed* type, portable code would need to check that the value will not overflow or underflow, as that is undefined behavior.  Then again, some implementations might not have `int64_t` either.  On many implementations, however, signed overflow or underflow will still give you a different number with the opposite sign, which will properly test as distinct.

Comment: Your alternative suggestion is elegant. Important to note, though, that it requires a check to make sure `m` is not the minimum or maximum value of its integer type.

Comment: @ptomato How to handle that? *Unsigned* arithmetic is guaranteed to wrap around, but the question asked about a signed type.  Signed integer overflow and underflow is undefined behavior. (And implementations typically do whatever the hardware does.) That said, on most compilers for most targets, the behavior is specified as producing a number of opposite sign, and the test will still work.

Answer (score 0):

A common theme among the other answers is the concern about whether or not you can assume that the doubles are implemented via IEEE 754 or not.

I'd argue that for many purposes your original method is best: cast the given int64_t to a double, then assign the result back to a second int64_t, and compare the two.

Regarding your concern about excess precision, that shouldn't be applicable as long as you know that the value has actually been written to memory and read back, because at that stage there shouldn't be any way for the compiler to store the "excess precision" for that variable. Based on the answers at your original link, I believe the following example would be enough to force that behavior:

```
bool losslessRoundTrip(int64_t valueToTest)
{
    double newRepresentation;
    *((volatile double *)&newRepresentation) = static_cast<double>(valueToTest);
    int64_t roundTripValue = static_cast<int64_t>(newRepresentation);
    return roundTripValue == valueToTest;
}
```

I suspect that simply declaring newRepresentation as volatile would be enough, but I don't use the volatile keyword enough to be sure, so I've simply adapted the solution from your link.

The nice thing about your original method is that it should work for pretty much anything supporting the right casts and operators, as long as you only care about whether you can come back to the initial type like this. For example, here is a generic implementation:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
bool losslessRoundTrip(T1 valueToTest)
{
    T2 newRepresentation;
    *((volatile T2 *)&newRepresentation) = static_cast<T2>(valueToTest);
    T1 roundTripValue = static_cast<T1>(newRepresentation);
    return roundTripValue == valueToTest;
}
```

Please note that this might not be the best answer for your question, because it still seems a cheat to check whether you can store it as a double by...storing it as a double. Still, I don't know how else to avoid relying on mechanics of the internal representation.

It also doesn't *quite* check whether it was losslessly stored in the double, but rather whether the round-trip from int64_t to double, and back to an int64_t is lossless on that platform. I don't know whether it's possible for there to be casting errors that cancel out when casts are applied in both directions (I'll appeal to someone with more knowledge for that), but in my opinion, I usually consider it close enough to "lossless" if I can get the initial value back if I convert back to the same type.

Comment: Good thinking with the `volatile` keyword. This will hopefully do what I _thought_ my original code would do. If it works on all the platforms where I need it to work, I'll give you the checkmark.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work on all platforms. Apparently compilers will do this even via a conversion that preserves the excess precision. Really good suggestion though.

Comment: Hmm...I still think the basic premise should work, because if we know that a value is really written to disk and then read back then there is no way to store the excess precision. The question therefore becomes how to force that to be the case. May I ask for an example of a platform where it didn't work so I may experiment?

Comment: Sure. See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=779399 for the actual use case. The architectures where it didn't work were armhf and ppc64el.

Comment: Ok awesome. I have an armhf setup I'll bring home from work tomorrow to see if I can reproduce the issue. I suspect my implementation of the idea is just slightly wrong somehow. This is the problem with volatile having so few valid use cases ;)

Comment: Just an update: I looked at it yesterday but haven't managed to get it to behave like the automated tests you linked (on my available compilers the code you have worked properly on armhf). I should be able to take another look some time this weekend to see if I can track down the root cause.

Comment: I've reproduced the failure from your link, but I have not yet been able to determine why. Looking at the generated assembly, the value is indeed being written to memory and read back. I'm surprised that any type of excess precision problem could occur in such a case. I'll take another look sometime this week, but if I can't figure it out by then I'll call it a loss and delete this answer. Oh well :/

Comment: Yeah, I basically chalked it up to "compilers are tricksy". But please don't delete the answer! I think it's still valuable.

Comment: As you allude to in the last paragraphs, the static_cast round-trip approach will be wrong with a value like `std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::max()` which is not precisely representable in `double`, but this function will return `true` for. It's not really safe due to various undefined and implementation-defined behaviour in cases like this (https://eel.is/c++draft/conv#fpint).

Answer (score -3):

You need to test the lower bits. If they are zero, the number will be stored losslessly.

Comment: Some proof example for this?

Comment: An IEEE double stores numbers with a binary floating point. So a number which is a multiple of a power of 2, ie has low bits zero, is like 3,000,000 in decimal. It can be represented exactly despite the approximation.

Comment: There's no guarantee the compiler or the target FPU uses that IEEE double encoding.

Comment: 2^1000 is exactly representable as a double and has zero as bottom bits. not gonna fit into a uint64_t though.

Comment: No, IEEE 754 is not requires. But it will use a binary floating point. It can represent multiples of powers of two exactly until it runs out of exponent, which means very large numbers indeed.

Comment: @malcolm: it could use a base which is a power of 2; at least one historic CPU used base 16. That will mean that the number of bits of precision varies depending on the first hex digit.