# C float operations have different results on i386 and arm, but why?

Tags: c, floating-point, arm

I have an implementation of an algorithm in C which uses floats.
When I compile and run on i386 I get different results to the results I get when I compile and run on armel.  In particular division-of-int-by-float, results in a different float.

I've extracted some code from my algorithm to demonstrate this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    float x = 4.80000019;
    float y = 4.80000019;
    int a = 38000;
    int b = 10000;
    int result = (a/x)+(b/y);
    printf("%.8f, %.8f\n", x, y); // same on i386 and armel
    printf("%f, %f\n", a/x, b/y); // slightly different on each
    printf("%d\n", result);       // prints 9999 on i386, and 10000 on armel
}
```

Can anybody explain why the two platforms generate different results?

Alex

Comment: Or just no FPU?. (Technically i386 doesn't have an FPU either, but I don't think there are compilers anymore who can target i386)

Comment: Do you actually mean i386? If so read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322797/problem-with-floating-point-precision-when-moving-from-i386-to-x86-64).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lookup 'excess precision'. To suppress it on a modern x86, compile with `-msse2 -mfpmath=sse`.

Comment: Thanks, that works - I now get the same results on both platforms.  BTW, do these gcc opts cost my program extra cycles?

Comment: @AlexZeffertt No, the modern SSE2 instructions should be slightly faster, if anything. The advantage of the historical instructions is that there are available on all x86 processors since the i386+i387.

Comment: @PascalCuoq:  Actually they go back to the 8088 and 8087 circa 1979.

Answer (score 4):

Can't test it for arm right now, but it have different results even on i386 and amd64 - on the same CPU, but compiled with -m32 flag. That's because of internal FPU structure - i387 uses 80bit floating point registers to perform operations, and then shrinks result back to 32bit floats (if requested). In amd64 insctruction set, SSE is used instead, which don't have that precise registers (but still it _at_least_ 32 bit). I suppose ARM have at least 32bits too, but anything above this is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard does not dictate how many things ought to be implemented and allows implementation-specific behavior. Floating point arithmetic is one such area where different implementations and therefore different results are perfectly OK. You either live with that or construct workarounds.

Comment: It is true that “the C standard [...] allows implementation-specific behavior”, but it is the wrong explanation. It is like saying “It is up to the implementation whether `int` can represent values larger than 32767, therefore it is normal for your program to produce different results”. In reality, **both processors strive to implement the IEEE 754 floating-point standard**, but what happens is that ARM does a better job than i386. R..'s answer even shows an option in GCC to generate modern instructions for exact single/double precision computations.

Comment: @PascalCuoq That is just a more detailed explanation than mine.